# Browser Extension: Chat room notification

Tags: gratis, chrome, firefox, notification

I'm looking for a browser extension (Chrome or Firefox) which notifies me whenever someone replies to my message in chat rooms, since most chat rooms are silent and most operators take way too much time to reply.

Comment: It might be relevant what kind of chat rooms you refer to. I don't think there's some "universal plugin", and different chats might follow different protocols. Could you please [edit] your post and add those details? Thanks!

Comment: @Izzy I'm looking for an extension that would work on as many chat rooms as possible, with no particular one in mind. The reason is, you visit a website, you need to chat with the support team and get notified regardless of what chat room software they are using, you don't care about that.

Comment: Afraid that lowers your chances for recommendations close to zero then. I'd at least include some examples of sites important to you, maybe there's a common nominator.